# The presenter the model and multiple data sources

Tags: java, android, oop, design-patterns, mvp

When implementing MVP in android the Presenter is responsible of the data. From examples I have found online the Presenter is passed in a datasource via dependency injection to use to fetch the data.
My question is how do we handle the case that the data come from multiple data sources? Should we pass multiple data sources to the presenter or create one data source for each data call?

Comment: yup, you have to create one data source for each data call

Comment: @jiteshmohite:But then for X call I would need X data sources and for every new I add I would need to modify everything?

Comment: can you share the link or example that you have mention in question

Comment: @jiteshmohite:Any google example e.g. http://glomadrian.github.io/blog/multiple-data-sources-and-caching/

Answer (score 1):

The presenter is not responsible for the data! The Model is responsible for the data. The idea is to have the model class be connected to the the various data sources. So, in practise this would look something like so:

Model contains data of some wiki page
Presenter has callabck methods for the view to inform about changes
View displays the data as specified by the presenter

Use-case: Updating some content

User clicks on "save" -> 
*View*

1. inform Presenter that user clicked on "save"

*Presenter*

1. Read content of the wiki page from view
2. call update method of model
3. tell view to display some loading spinner or so

*Model*

1. updates local cache or storage (for offline use)
2. asynchronously sets server call to store the updated data
3. when server call is done informs the presenter that the data set changed and the saving is done

*Presenter*

1. Retrieves data from the model
2. Updates view (by passing the model's data to the view)
3. Tells the view to stop the loading spinner.

As you can see, the model is the one responsible to communicate with various data sources, while the presenter orchestrates user actions and model changes.

See also http://www.tinmegali.com/en/model-view-presenter-android-part-1/

Comment: So is the model a combination of multiple data sources? So we have 1 model for various type of data types?